# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 32 during a self-made layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using tensorflow 2.2.0 in a google colab notebook. I've some self-made activation layers but the problem comes when I try to use that specific one:

```
class MPELU(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
"""
Multiple Parametric Exponential Linear Units.
""" 
def __init__(self, channel_wise=True, **kwargs):
    super(MPELU, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.channel_wise = channel_wise

def build(self, input_shape):
    shape = [1]

    if self.channel_wise:
        shape = [int(input_shape[-1])]  # Number of channels

    self.alpha = self.add_weight(name='alpha', shape=shape, dtype=K.floatx(),
                                 initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=-1, maxval=1),
                                 trainable=True)
    self.beta = self.add_weight(name='beta', shape=shape, dtype=K.floatx(),
                                initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=0.0, maxval=1),
                                trainable=True)

    # Finish buildidng
    super(MPELU, self).build(input_shape)


@tf.function
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    positive = tf.keras.activations.relu(inputs)
    negative = self.alpha * (K.exp(-tf.keras.activations.relu(-inputs) * cons_greater_zero(self.beta)) - 1)

    return positive + negative

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape
```

The error code is the following:

```
    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 32 for '{{node mpelu/mul_10}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](mpelu/Neg_11, mpelu/add_10)' with input shapes: [?,4,4,64], [32].
```

I used a print function to print shape in every call and that's the results:

```
(None, 16, 16, 32)
(None, 7, 7, 32)
(None, 7, 7, 32)
(None, 7, 7, 32)
(None, 7, 7, 32)
(None, 4, 4, 64)
```

Comment: Can you also add the code and how you come up with that shape in every call function.

Comment: Okey, this part is a bit complicated. The full code is on github, is a suite for creating ordinal deep learning experiments: https://github.com/chema969/spp
I use the beckamresnet layer architecture (defined in net_keras.py and resnet.py) with that activation function (defined in activations.py). The main experiment file, where fit and compile are called are in experiment.py. Wish it helps, I'm sorry I couldn't give the exact code.